# How to characterize Machiavelli's phrase, "The ends justify the means"?

Tags: expressions, terminology, colloquialisms, rhetorical-devices, politics

This question has been raised and thoroughly discussed: "How to characterize the phrase, 'The ends justify the means.'" I wish to add a thought. As I was writing a book for publication, I came upon the same question about the phrase. Unlike the other previous answers in a well-thought-out thread, I concluded the phrase—based on the original question—is best described as a "proposition" since Machiavelli was a diplomat. The statement doesn't rise to a principal because it is debatable; however, it does spur an enduring (political and moral) discussion and is, therefore, a proposition.

Comment: This would benefit from a link to the original discussion and some clarity about what you want from an answer here.

Comment: This maxim is generally incorrectly attributed to Nicolas Machiavelli: his work "The Prince" expresses this philosophy in detail, but without ever using this expression.  Some persons attribute the sentence "la fin justifie les moyens" to Philippe Van Den Clyte, [lord of Commynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_Commines), who wanted to justify his betrayal. But, I can't likewise find the adage in his memories.

Comment: The original cite was https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420078/is-there-a-name-for-the-expression-the-end-justifies-the-means

Comment: You mean that none of the definitions posted in the answers to the original question  suits you? In case you can add your own to the original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a name for the expression "the end justifies the means?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420078/is-there-a-name-for-the-expression-the-end-justifies-the-means)

Comment: Graffito's reply is well taken. @Gio Many of the originally posted definitions made sense to me, but none exactly met my sense of the phrase "The ends..." And I couldn't add my two cents to the original question because the thread had long been closed. I'm new here and do not have the reputation to comment.

Comment: @Jeffsbooks but I think you can add your own answer to the original question.

Comment: @Gio Other than recasting the question as I did, what's the workaround to posting on the original closed thread as a member working toward reputation?

Comment: A reposted  a question will just be closed as a duplicate. An answer to the original question will remain visible to future visitors. That’s how SE works.

Comment: @Gio Thank you. I appreciate that.

Comment: When you post an answer to an old question, it will appear on  top of the “active questions” list so that users can see it and up/downvote etc. So, no matter how old a question is, new additions  will be immediately visible.